# Temporarily hiding HTML / Bootstrap elements is changing their widths

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

Newbie here, have mercy :D

So I have a div with two tables in it, which both include several Bootstrap buttons. I stretched them to 100% width so that they fill the whole table (which fill the whole div in return).

Whenever I click one of the buttons, I want to hide the tables and replace them by some other div that was hidden before. Also, a back button is appearing that should reverse that process.

Most of this works fine, however, after using the back button to get back to the initial state, the buttons aren't filling the whole width anymore. I'm not sure what could help, as I only touched the style of the tables, not their elements, and the tables still fill 100% width of their div as seen by the borders (see below).

I'm inlucing a minimal working example:

```
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="3600">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>Hello!</title>
    <style>
        #options-div {
            display: flex;
        }

        .action-divs, #back-button {
            display: none;
        }

        .options-table {
            table-layout: fixed;
            border: 2px solid green;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .btn-dark {
            width: 100%;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="options-div">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="back-button">Back</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <table class="options-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-block" id="jet-button">Jet</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div class="action-divs" id="jet-div">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

for the markup. A div with a table with one button.

And the javascript:

```
var jetButton = document.querySelector("#jet-button");
jetButton === null || jetButton === void 0 ? void 0 : jetButton.addEventListener("click", handleJet);

var backButton = document.querySelector("#back-button");
backButton === null || backButton === void 0 ? void 0 : backButton.addEventListener("click", handleBack);

function handleJet() {
    var optionsTables = document.querySelector(".options-table");
    optionsTables.style.display = "none";
    
    var jetDiv = document.querySelector("#jet-div");
    jetDiv.style.display = "flex";
    backButton.style.display = "flex";
}
function handleBack() {
    var optionsTables = document.querySelector(".options-table");
    optionsTables.style.display = "flex";
    optionsTables.style.tableLayout = "fixed";

    backButton.style.display = "none";
    
    var jetDiv = document.querySelector("#jet-div");
    jetDiv.style.display = "none";
}
```

Sorry for the TypeScript conversion stuff, hopefully it's readable enough. Basically on click of my button, I want to hide the table and display another div and the back button. On click of the back button, I want to hide the div and the back button again and re-display the initial table (with the button in it).
I already tried Bootstrap classes like btn-block, none did work though.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will be nice if you try to remove all the for loops, try to accomplish it with only 1 element first.

Comment: Thanks, did so. Should be more readable now, same result though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you add `flex` to the table element. Your `button` element will take the 100% width but after flex applied the `td` element is minimum to content

```html
   <table class="options-table">
      <tr>
         <td>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-block" id="jet-button">Jet</button>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

you can try to use  `align-items: stretch;` and always leave flex  on the table.

Also, i would recommend to use `classList` to add and remove classes on the element instead of change styles directly.
[MDN element classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Thanks, simply creating some "invisible" class with display = none worked perfectly when adding / removing the class at appropriate places!